# Why does this for loop don't work in java?

Tags: java, loops

I have this exercise code to calculate the future hour:

```
public static void main(String[]   args) {
Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
String amPm;
System.out.println("Write an hour (lower o equal to 12) ");
int startHour = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println("write the number of hours to sum ");
scanner.nextLine();
int hoursToSum = scanner.nextInt();

System.out.println("am or pm? (1/0)");
int selection = scanner.nextInt();

if (selection == 1) {
amPm = ".am";
}
else {
amPm = ".pm";
}

for(int i = 0; i == hoursToSum; i++) {
startHour ++;
if (startHour > 12) {
startHour = 1;
if (amPm.equals(".am")) {
amPm = ".pm";
}
else {
amPm = ".am";
}
}
}
System.out.println("it´s gonna be: " + startHour + amPm);
}
```

But it doesn't work, except with the values 12  to startHour and 0 to hourToSum.

I tried with while loop and it worked!

I Know both, for and while loop, are able to perform the same task.
So, why does this happen?

```
 int i = 0;
while(i < hoursToSum) {
startHour ++;
if (startHour > 12) {
startHour = 1;
if (amPm.equals(".am")) {
amPm = ".pm";
}
else {
amPm = ".am";
}
}
i ++;

}
```

Comment: `i == hoursToSum` is not the same as `i < hoursToSum`; so your `while` and `for` behave differently.

Comment: Thanks Amadan, it worked

Comment: Please format this illegible mess properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on Amadan's comment, a for loop consists of three parts:
 1. An initialization with variable declaration
 2. A condition
 3. An iteration, or change of state at the end of the loop

These things happen in a while loop also, but are placed differently

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {  //(initialization;condition;iteration)
    doStuff();
}
```

This initializes i to 0, increments it each time the code in the block completes, and breaks out of the loop if i exceeds 12.

```
int i = 0;       // initialization
while (i < 12) { //condition
    doStuff();
    i++;         //iteration
}
```

The error is in the condition portion of the for loop, where you are checking i == hoursToSum instead of i < hoursToSum, as you did in the while loop

Comment: Thanks Jeremy you're right, I missed the condition.